# Record Link Unfurling in Salesforce for Slack

Tags: slack, slack-salesforce-app

With the new `Salesforce for Slack` integration (new as of Spring 2023), I am unable to get a Salesforce Record Link (for Opportunity) unfurled as expected ([Unfurled Links in Slack Messages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.slack_apps_digital_hq_unfurling.htm&type=5)).

When using the [Send Slack Message](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_slack_send_message.htm&type=5) core action from a Flow, initially I thought setting the `Record Id` parameter in the flow action would automatically add the little box in Slack with the record info. In the `Initial Slack Setup` in Setup, in the `Verify Data Sharing Options` I have "Show Record Name and Object Type" in `Set Record Detail Security for Your Salesforce Apps` and "Name, Type, and Preview Button" for `Unfurling Options for Salesforce for Slack App`.

However, I noticed today that the Record Id parameter in the flow action says `The record ID to send to the view. Defining a view is a pilot feature`. So looks like that's not actually available yet.

Thus, I added a direct link to the record in the `Slack Message`, and the Slack message correctly displays the link. But there is still no link unfurling (aka little box in Slack).

How can I get the Opportunity record link to unfurl like Salesforce says it will?

[image]

Comment: Update (related to below answer asking if I solved this): unfortunately I still haven't found a solution to this problem.